# Excel VBA Using cell value in vlookup formula

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I am trying to create a vlookup to a worksheet that has the same name as the cell value in my active sheet.

I created the following thinking I could use the 'str' in my vlookup formula but, I get 'Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error'

```
Sub copy()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim str As String

    str = Cells(1, 5).Value

    With Sheets("Overview")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
            .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2, & str &!B:F,5,FALSE)"
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `"=VLOOKUP(B2," & str & "!B:F,5,FALSE)"`

Comment: @ScottCraner This is a simple syntax error: should we close this question as of no much merit? Otherwise, you can post your answer and I will upvote it (btw, the other posted answer actually contains your solution, but you have posted it first, so the credit should go to you). Best regards,

Comment: @AlexBell we posted at nearly the same time, I almost deleted my comment.  I am okay with giving the credit for the correct answer to Jordan.  If I were to post an answer it would be identical to his.  But thank you.  I doubt this would get enough votes to close.

Comment: @ScottCraner Well, you've posted your comment a minute before that other (identical) answer, so kudos is going to you, but if you decide so, then it's OK to keep this question open w/given answer. Best regards to you and other folks on this thread,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `str` in VBA but referred to it in the formula without closing off the quotation marks, try this:

```
Sub copy()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim str As String

str = Cells(1, 5).Value

With Sheets("Overview")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    With .Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2," & str & "!B:F,5,FALSE)"
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Scott and Jordan ... makes perfect sense now. I added the quotations and it works perfectly !

Comment: No worries, if you could just mark this as correct it will save others looking at the question to help with an issue that has already been resolve. Thanks